# How to uninstall steam

Tags: uninstall, steam, software-uninstall

ive looked at the other answers on other questions and typed in the code that i needed to but this keeps popping up

```
"Reading package lists... Error!  
 E: Encountered a section with no Package: header  
 E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists  /repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en
 E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."
```

Any help .thanks

Comment: refer [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/730/apt-get-upgrade-fails-with-errors-e-encountered-a-section-with-no-package-h)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me - simply remove that file with:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en
```

If any other errors with `repo.steampowered.com` files occur, just delete the file causing the problems.